# OpenSUSE version of arandr

Tags: software-installation, opensuse, multi-monitor, xrandr

`arandr` is a Debian/Ubuntu version of `xrandr` with a graphical interface to make it easier to use. I want the same package on OpenSUSE to use on my laptop. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the [Open Build Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Build_Service)'s search came up with: [apparently, someone (AlexFrost) created a package](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=arandr&project=home%3AAlexFrost).  I suspect you can just use these binaries.  (I have no idea if this Build Service is already somehow integrated with the standard distribution tools, I guess it is?)